# How to delete all lines after line N that match "ABC"

Tags: vim

Say I'm editing a 1000 line file.

I want to keep lines 1-500 untouched.

But I want to delete all lines after line 500 that match "ABC"

How can i do this?

I can do all lines line this

```
:g/ABC/d
```

And i can delete all lines in range

```
:501,$d
```

But how to delete only lines that match a pattern?

(Been using vi since 1989.  Just can't think how to do this!  Sorry if it's obvious)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`:global` takes a range, too. Thus you want:

`501,$g/ABC/d` :-)

Comment: Excellent!  I guess I always thought global meant global and didn't even think it might accept a range.  Cheers.

Comment: Maybe ed/ex/vi didn't support ranges in the beginning, so it seems weird to us nowadays. But it's just a guess!